# Связи между таблицами. SQL Server

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Подскажите, правильно ли я начинаю выстраивать БД:

пока есть 3 таблицы: `dbo.Exam`, `dbo.Offset`, `dbo.Session`.

У **экзамена** и **зачета** схожая структура: `id` `name` `date`.

Структура  `dbo.Session`: `id` `fromDate` `toDate`.

**Сессия** одна, но у нее может быть несколько зачетов и экзаменов.

Как я предполагаю, мне нужно сделать связь **Многие ко многим**.

Поэтому делаю следующее:

```
create table dbo.StudentSession
(
   SessionId int foreign key references dbo.Session(Id),
   ExamId int foreign key references dbo.Exam(Id),
   OffsetId int foreign key references dbo.Offset(Id),
   constraint id primary key(SessionId, ExamId, OffsetId)
)
```

P.s как я потом могу ссылаться на `id` `dbo.StudentSession` из других таблиц?

Comment: Почему экзамен и зачёт - это РАЗНЫЕ сущности? ведь это одна сущность, просто атрибуты немного разные... и основной вопрос - в том, являются они самостоятельными сущностями, или атрибутами сущности предмет (который может иметь мультиатрибут Контроль с атрибутом Тип со значениями Зачёт, Проект, Экзамен, ...). Именно от последнего факта и пляшет схема. А то, что есть сейчас - прямой путь на поле с граблями имхо.

Comment: @Akina делалось 2 сущности с расчетом на масштабируемость по отношению к зачетам и экзаменам(в случае необходимости добавление каких-либо доп. атрибутов и т.д.) и,конечно,нормализацю.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы утверждаете, что **одна** сессия может содержать **несколько экзаменов и зачетов** , то это две связи **один ко многим**.
Рациональнее создать таблицы **SessionExam**  **SessionOffset** , состоящие соответственно из `sessionId, examId` и `sessionId, offsetId`. Это позволит не плодить записи в будущей таблице **StudentSession**. Соответственно потом из этих таблиц по внешнему ключу  `sessionId` можно будет получить всю необходимую информацию об экзаменах и зачётах по **id** сессии.

Comment: Спасибо за отклик! Позвольте вопрос: вы утверждаете, что создать две отдельных сущности и заносить туда записи будет рациональнее. Но ведь количество записей в этих двух сущностях будет не меньше количества записей в созданной мной таблице dbo.StudentSession?

Comment: Количество строк может и совпадать, но рассмотрим ситуацию, когда **экзаменов больше, чем зачётов**. Тогда у нас появляются NULL значения в записях зачётов, а тк судя по тэгу вопроса речь идёт об sql-server, занимать на машине эти null поля будут как полноценный int . [подробнее](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731172/how-much-size-null-value-takes-in-sql-server). Следующий момент -  это возможные сложности при запросе с получением null - значений id этих зачётов, в то время как в варианте, предложенном мной можно изначально сделать поля **examId и offsetId** non-null. Двойной профит.

Comment: Немного не понял вас, в каком моменте там будет Null? Если будет выборочный select: то есть можно добавить в сессию 2 экзамена и 1 зачет,к примеру, и это вовсе не значит, что где-то появится Null из-за неодинакового числа экзаменов и зачетов.